# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib when running nginx and mysql after macOS upgrade to Catalina

Tags: mysql, macos, nginx, openssl, homebrew

I have updated my development enviroment to the latest version of OSX Catalina. Then nginx and mysql server has stopped working. When I try to run any of these I get the same error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/nginx
  Reason: image not found
```

I´m reading a lot of posts and they say mostly the same: Openssl is a dependency library with the new OsX. Fix, looks pretty ease, removed the openssl installation and re-installed the latest version, which is openssl@1.1. I have already done it, but however I´m still getting the same error.

I think it´s because according to the error message, both nginx and mysql are expecting the version 1.0.0 and I´m installing the latest 1.1. I have been trying to install the version 1.0 with homebrew, but I´m not able to find it. Is it possible to get this old version? Or should I upgrade my nginx and mysql software versions?

Comment: I'm having the same Issue. I'm guessing if I just have to reinstall MySQL again...

Comment: I´m getting totally crazy. Please let me know if you solve it.

Comment: I already wrote an answer about how I solve my issues. I think in your case you could install again MySQL and Nginx. (or upgrade it likes I did)

Comment: I upgraded with `brew`. 
`$ brew update && brew upgrade`
It solved this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue, not for upgrading to Catalina but because of installing a program which upgrade my version of OpenSSL, so it brokes other apps which depended on OpenSSL. 
In my case Ruby (2.3.8 with RVM) and MySQL (MariaDb in fact). In the case of Ruby, it was incompatible with the new version of OpenSSL, so I had to install it with pkg depdendencies for RVM

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall 2.3.8  --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

In the case of MySQL I just upgraded it, so it got installed with the new openSSL on my System.

```
brew upgrade mariadb
```

Thats solves my issues. I think in your case you could upgrade (or uninstall and reintall) MySQL and Nginx, so they will correctly use the new version of OpenSSL.

(P.D. In the case of MySQL it conserved my databases without problems)

Comment: I will try it and let you know. The bad news is that I installed a new version of mysql 8 and now I cannot see my older version, neither my development database. I´m afraid I lost it.

Comment: Now I use MariaDB, because i feel it more stable than the last versions of MySQL. And basically is the same, as the one of the more stable MySQL versions (5.x)